# Access other attributes of the instance with __getattr__(self, name)

Tags: python, object, attributes

In Python's [documentation, on the `__getattr__` function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) it says:

> Note that if the attribute is
>   found through the normal mechanism, __getattr__() is not called. (This is an intentional asymmetry
>   between __getattr__() and __setattr__().) This is done both for efficiency reasons and because
>   otherwise __getattr__() would have no way to access other attributes of the instance.

I have a problem understanding the last statement:

> would have no way to access other attributes of the instance

How exactly would it have no way to access other attributes? (I guess it has something to do with infinite recursion but aren't there other ways to acces instance attributes, like from `self.__dict__` directy?)

Comment: How would you access `self.__dict__` if that called `__getattr__`, although I don't see why you couldn't us `object.__getattr__(self,key)` for new style classes ...

Comment: @mgilson: Exactly! For `__setattr__` I can bypass the infinite recursion. Why not for `__getattr__`?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have an infinite recursion if you tried to use `self.__dict__[key]` as `self.__dict__` would call `__getattr__`, etc, etc.  Of course, you can break out of this cycle if you use `object.__getattr__(self,key)`, but *that only works for new style classes*.  There is no general mechanism that you could use with *old style* classes.

Note that you don't have this problem with `__setattr__` because in that case, you *can* use `self.__dict__` directly (Hence the asymmetry).

Comment: Though you should probably use `super(cls, self).__getattr__()`, as you can't be sure what your ancestors are doing.

Comment: @sr2222 -- using `super` isn't a way to get around knowing what your ancestors are doing.  Who knows if calling `ancestor.__getattr__()` will mess up what you're trying to do in `__getattr__`?  You always need to have *some* knowledge about your ancestors.

Comment: True.  But just blindly calling `object` certainly doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The `__getattribute__()` magic method is the pair with `__setattr__()`, but with great power comes great responsibility.  `__getattr__()` is provided so that you don't have to assume the great responsibility part.  As @mgilson points out in the comments, if `__getattr__()` worked as `__getattribute__()` does, you would be unable to access any attributes off the instance from within `__getattr__()`, because even to look at `self.__dict__` you need to use the attribute lookup machinery.

Comment: But why not `object.__getattr__(self,key)` to avoid the infinite recursion (as you do when you use `__setattr__` for example).

Comment: That's what you do do when you use `__getattribute__()`, but `__getattr__()` gives you a nice way to keep all the machinery of attribute lookup cleanly hidden away.  `__getattribute__()` is basically for cases where you want to completely reengineer attribute lookup, whereas `__getattr__()` is for handling a few special cases in an otherwise regular object (though even `__getattr__()` is usually overkill, and a property or decorator will often suffice).